# iOS iTunes Can't remove devices: An unspecified error occurred. Please refresh and try again

Tags: ios

I want to reset the device lists form the iOS dev portal.

But When I click on continue Button I got this error:
An unspecified error occurred.
Please refresh and try again.

I got this error since 3 days.

EDIT: I tried on Windows, OSX, Chrome, Firefox...

Comment: Having the same problem on two different accounts!

Comment: Same problem here. It's very annoying.

Comment: This question belongs on http://apple.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I switched my browser to safari and it worked , previously i was working in Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if the iOS dev center portal is updated but I finally succeed to remove all my devices excepted one.

**Unselect all your devices but select only 1 device in your device list.
Then click continue.**

That worked for me.